# Doctrine Installation with composer not working

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, composer-php

When I try to install the `Doctrine MongoDB ODM library` and its dependencies with Composer using the following command:

```
composer require "doctrine/mongodb-odm=~1.0.0-BETA10@dev"
```

I get the following:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA10 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 
    -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA11 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 
    -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.x-dev requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 
    -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.1.6 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev 
    -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.0-dev) installed.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.1.5 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev 
    -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.0-dev) installed.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm ~1.0.0-BETA10@dev 
    -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0-BETA10, 1.0.0-BETA11, 1.0.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My mongo php extension version is **1.6.0 dev**.

I am a noob, please help me with this.

Comment: having kinda the same issue, thoughts: doctrine/mongodb 1.0.9 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.0-dev) installed.

Comment: solving this by install mongodb on php (http://php-osx.liip.ch/ for ex). Then add the 1.0.9 dependence : php composer.phar require doctrine/mongodb:1.0.9